# How to download word file using php on chrome and IE

Tags: php, download, header, ms-word, readfile

I have a problem while downloading word file using php header and readfile function.
It is responding well while download in Mozilla Firefox, but not working well when use google chrome and IE. Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Here is my code:

```
switch(strtolower($ext))
    {
        case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break; 
        case "docx": $ctype="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"; break;                       
        default: $ctype="application/octet-stream"; 
    }

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    //header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: ".$ctype." "); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($rw['FINALDOCNAME']));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header('Pragma: private');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($rw['FINALDOCNAME']));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($filepath);
```

Comment: Have you checked that the file actual exists? Why not check both `filesize` and `readfile` return values to ensure that they are what are expected.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code.

```
<?php
$fdl = @fopen($filePath,'rb');
header("Status: 200");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
header("Pragma: hack");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false);
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Type: $ctype");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\""); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length:".filesize($filePath));  
if($fdl)
{
    while(!feof($fdl)) {
        print(fread($fdl, filesize($filePath)));
        flush();
        if (connection_status()!=0) 
        {
            @fclose($fdl);
            die();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Very awesome... This solved my issue of docx corruption. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$todayDate = date('d-m-Y');
$filename = 'untitled.docx';
header('content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.'-'.$todayDate.'.xls');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
echo file_get_contents($filename);
?>
```