# How to update legacy PHP code that is corrupting docx and xlsx files?

Tags: php, header, docx, corruption, xlsx

I am working with some legacy PHP code and have run into Word Doc (docx) and Spreadsheet (xlsx) corruption.

Here is the current code in the download.php file:

```
$new_file_name = stripMySlashes($filename); 
    header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=$new_file_name");
    header("Content-type: application/octetstream");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    $client=getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT");
    $fp=fopen('uploaded_files/'.$folder.'/'.$filename,"r");
    $str=fread($fp,filesize('uploaded_files/'.$folder.'/'.$filename));
    echo $str;
    fclose($fp);
```

How can I avoid checking for a bunch of filetypes in a case statement for example? I tried code like this with no luck

```
$file="test.docx"; 
header("Pragma: public"); 
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$file); 
header("Content-type: ".mime_content_type($file)); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
ob_clean(); 
flush(); 
readfile($file);
```

Any help is extremely appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Props to [How to download word file using php on chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218231/how-to-download-word-file-using-php-on-chrome-and-ie)

I used this to fix the docx corruption issue...

```
$new_file_name = stripMySlashes($filename); 

$fdl = @fopen('uploaded_files/'.$folder.'/'.$filename,'rb');
header("Status: 200");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
header("Pragma: hack");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false);
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Type: application/octetstream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$new_file_name."\""); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length:".filesize('uploaded_files/'.$folder.'/'.$filename));  
if($fdl)
{
    while(!feof($fdl)) {
        print(fread($fdl, filesize('uploaded_files/'.$folder.'/'.$filename)));
        flush();
        if (connection_status()!=0) 
        {
            @fclose($fdl);
            die();
        }
    }
}
```